# Google static map radius to zoom

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps

I'm developing a web service in `PHP` that gets a latitude, longitude and a radius in kilometers and generate [google static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Also I display all points from my database in that radius.

My question is how I can covert my `radius` in google's `zoom` parameter to ensure that all points are visible on the map?

something like: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&[*THIS PARAMETER*zoom=13]&size=600x300&markers.......`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated at [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates):

> Because the basic Mercator Google Maps tile is 256 x 256 pixels.
>   Also note that every zoom level, the map has 2 <sup>n</sup> tiles.

Meaning that at zoomLevel 2, the pixels in any direction of a map are = 256 * 2² = 1024px.

Taking into account that the earth has a perimeter of ~40,000 kilometers, in zoom 0, every pixel ~= 40,000 km/256 = 156.25 km
At zoom 9, pixels are 131072:
1px = 40,000 km / 131072 = 0.305 km ... and so on.

If your image is 640 x 640 px,and you are using zoom 9, this means that you will cover ~ 640 * 0.305  ~= 195km. So your radius is approx 100km.
Everytime you zoom++, the radius is the half.

If you use zoom 15 (1px = 0.00478km) your image will cover ~3km wide (radius 1.5km).

Take into account that as you go further to north or south, the real distance is less, as the distortion is bigger.

You could use as parameter something like zoom = Floor(log<sub>2</sub> (EarthP * 2 PixMap / (256 *radius))).

- EarthP = Earth perimeter at that Latitude (in km)
- PixMap = Pixels of the map you will display
- radius = radius you want to be displayed in your image (in km)
- log <sub>2</sub>= logarithm in base 2

note: to convert  log<sub>2</sub> into regular log just make this:
Floor((log (EarthP * 2 PixMap / (256 *radius)))/log 2)

Reference for [Logarithms in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LatLngBounds and the map.fitBounds method... [Google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: Ok, sorry. as far as I can remember I thought if you had markers defined and don't supply 'zoom', then the map will automatically include all points. (if you have no markers you have to supply 'zoom')